# Compiling program using cgal_create_CMakeLists fails to include headers

Tags: cgal

I am trying to compile my own simple program that uses the CGAL library. To do this I am using the cgal_create_CMakeLists script provided with the latest CGAL distribution. Following the procedure outlined in the user manual, I run the script, then `cmake`, and then attempt to `make`. The `make` fails with the error `/Users/morton/test/cgal/cgal_test.cpp:39:10: fatal error: 
      'CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h' file not found`

I believe I am following the instructions to the letter, and can't see a step where I can set the path to this header file explicitly.

I run:
`sh cgal_create_CMakeLists -s cgal_test`
`cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/usr/local/lib/cmake/CGAL .`
`make`

Below I have posted the CMakeLists.txt file that is generated, and the output that I get from the cmake step.

```
CGAL_COMPONENTS: 
moving CMakeLists.txt to CMakeLists.txt.bak ...

# Created by the script cgal_create_CMakeLists
# This is the CMake script for compiling a set of CGAL applications.

project( cgal_test )


cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

# CGAL and its components
find_package( CGAL QUIET COMPONENTS  )

if ( NOT CGAL_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")
  return()  

endif()


# Boost and its components
find_package( Boost REQUIRED )

if ( NOT Boost_FOUND )

  message(STATUS "This project requires the Boost library, and will not be compiled.")

  return()  

endif()

# include for local directory

# include for local package


# Creating entries for target: cgal_test
# ############################

add_executable( cgal_test  cgal_test.cpp )

add_to_cached_list( CGAL_EXECUTABLE_TARGETS cgal_test )

# Link the executable to CGAL and third-party libraries
target_link_libraries(cgal_test   ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )


created CMakeLists.txt in /Users/morton/test/cgal ...
```

```
-- __cplusplus is 199711
-- Boost version: 1.69.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   thread
--   system
--   chrono
--   date_time
--   atomic
-- Boost include dirs: /usr/local/include
-- Boost libraries:    /usr/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_chrono-mt.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib;/usr/local/lib/libboost_atomic-mt.dylib
-- Boost version: 1.69.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/morton/test/cgal
```

As I understand it, this process should have found the location of the headers and set it automatically. However the `make` does not seem to know here the included files are. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The cmake generation scripts are not working very well. Replace
`target_link_libraries(cgal_test   ${CGAL_LIBRARIES} ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )`
with `target_link_libraries(cgal_test   CGAL::CGAL ${CGAL_3RD_PARTY_LIBRARIES} )`
It should work better. Otherwise you will need to call include_directories() to include the CGAL headers but I am not sure of the variable name. Somtehing like ${CGAL_INCLUDE_DIR }, but it shouldn't be necessary if you use the `::` form.

Comment: @mgimeno Thanks, this fixes it.